# Canon C100 mk1 AVCHD vs MP4

Tags: codec, video-recording, mp4, canon

I recently bought a Canon C100 mk1 after lots of comparing, specs etc.

Now I have a question which I cannot really find a final answer for on the interweb.

The Canon C100 can record in either AVCHD or MP4. Which one is better to use? 
AVCHD is a single wrapped file with all the clips in
MP4 is just all the clips (Currently like my Canon 7D)

Most people seem to use the AVCHD, but I have seen screenshots or images of the cameras that are set to MP4, and I am unable to find a reason why people choose one over the other.

I shot a wedding in AVCHD and edited it with FCPX (not the most recent version), and I have done all the options of trans-coding, changing the 50i to progressive, etc. that others have recommended online, but some of my shots are still giving me interlacing.

Would shooting in MP4 eliminate these issues? *When I shoot on my Canon 7D, it is not there - only a bit of jello.*

The most I can find is a comparison between AVCHD and MP4 for quality (to which I cannot see much difference) or a comparison between the mk1 and the mk2 which is not really answering my question.

I have a wedding coming up next weekend and would like to shoot with the best option. I don't think I'm going to have enough spare time to do a test using both codecs.

Comment: did you find your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, the C100 Mk I **DOES NOT** offer an MP4 option, only a AVCHD option. I'm assuming you meant the MKII as you said 'recently bought'.

If you look at the specs of the C100 MK II you'll see in MP4 mode you can't record interlaced, but in AVCHD you can (but you don't have to if you are at 28 mbps). So basically you can't go wrong (aka get interlaced files) with MP4, with that being said, you can also use the AVCHD wrapper @ 28 mbps and not get interlaced files (look out for the 'i' next to the framerates).

People primarily use the MP4 wrapper in the C100 MK II because it has the capability of recording at a higher bit rate (35 mbps) which means you have more information to work with when you get into the editing room, its good for color grading, and in some cases has less noise. I also find that MP4 works better inside of PP CC.

Also shooting in MP4 will probably not have much an effect on jello (although its never something I've experience in my C100's) but not shooting in interlaced will definitely help due to the way interlaced works (capturing every other line).

I'm a C100 MK I & MK II user ;)

Answer (score 0):

Avchd has better audio and MP4 is easier to work with and will play on more devices without transcoding. If you can edit Avchd easily use it. They use the same codec so quality will be about the same(you wouldn't notice it in use)

Answer (score 0):

Quality wise they are the same

- AVCHD = great for in-camera editing, and very flexible. Limited
  compatibility with devices/softare
- MP4 = great compatibility, can only be edited with
  external software on computer

If you have experience with editing, and your editing software supports avchd then choose that (as you already have done)

Answer (score 0):

Both have comparable quality. Not going to repeat anything already said but a lot of it comes down to what are you going to edit with, are there other cameras, and what type of editing. Avchd degrades quicker with color correction and heavy effects. Though mp4 is not much better. One thing to not is both avchd and mp4 are wrappers and not the codec which is what codes the video. Both on the c100 are h264 codec which means basically the same quality. As also said the bit rates differ some because of compression and storing method. You want to stick with all the same media when editing so it other media is avchd then use that or likewise with mp4. Also the software you use can influence your decision certain editors handle different formats better. Premiere typically handle mp4 better same with final cut.